# LoDash - group by array property without taking the values as one key

Tags: javascript, arrays, coffeescript, lodash

I need to group an array of objects by a property that is an array too.

This is my initial array

```
var videos = [
   {
    name: 'Video 1',
    productInfo:{
        categories: ['cat1', 'cat2']}
   },
   {
    name: 'Video 2',
    productInfo:{
        categories: ['cat2']}
   },
   {
    name: 'Video 3',
    productInfo:{
        categories: ['cat1', 'cat3']}   
   }
];
```

When I use this

```
_.groupBy videos, 'productInfo.categories'
```

My response is

```
 {
  'cat1, cat2': Array[1],
  'cat1, cat3': Array[1],
  'cat2': Array[1]
 }
```

I already tried with the answer of another guy that asked the same problem, with a different result.

Trying his solution

```
_.groupBy _.flatten _.pluck videos, 'productInfo.categories'
```

I get

```
{
  'cat1': ['cat1', 'cat1'], 
  'cat2': ['cat2', 'cat2'],
  'cat3': ['cat3'] 
}
```

And I need as a response

```
{
'cat1': [videoObject, videoObject], 
'cat2': [videoObject, videoObject],
'cat3': [videoObject] 
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

```
var res = _.reduce(videos, function(result, video){
    return _.reduce(video.productInfo.categories, function(acc, category){
        (acc[category] || (acc[category] = [])).push(video);
        return acc;
    }, result);
}, {});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is roughly what you are looking for. There may be more elegant solutions..

```
var videos = [
  {
    name: 'Video 1',
    productInfo: {
      categories: ['cat1', 'cat2']
    }
  },
  {
    name: 'Video 2',
    productInfo: {
      categories: ['cat2']
    }
  },
  {
   name: 'Video 3',
    productInfo: {
      categories: ['cat1', 'cat3']
    }
  }
];

var collection = {};
_.each(videos, function(video) {
  _.each(video.productInfo.categories, function (category) {
    collection[category] = collection[category] ? collection[category] : [];
    collection[category].push(video);
  })
});
```

Comment: Almost, to get the expected result with your code, transform should look like this: `var result = _.transform(videos, function (collection, video) { ... }, { });`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var result = _.chain(videos)
  .map(function(video) {
    return _.map(_.get(video, 'productInfo.categories', []), function ( cat ) {
      return _.extend({ '_category': cat }, video);
    });
  })
  .flatten()
  .groupBy('_category')
  .value();
```

Not a one liner, but it gets the job done. Basically I go through each video object and look at the categories array. For each category, I create the same video object and add a fake property with value being the category I'm looking at (here I call it `_category`). I then call `_.groupBy` on the fake property.

If you want to get rid of the fake property in the results, you can add another function to the chain that omits the property:

```
var result = _.chain(videos)
  .map(function(video) {
    return _.map(_.get(video, 'productInfo.categories', []), function ( cat ) {
      return _.extend({ '_category': cat }, video);
    });
  })
  .flatten()
  .groupBy('_category')
  .transform(function(result, videos, category) {
    result[ category ] = _.map(videos, function(video) {
      return _.omit(video, '_category')
    });
  })
  .value();
```

Not the most efficient solution.